# Stream TextReader to a File

Tags: c#, stream, textreader

I have a `TextReader` object.

Now, I want to stream the whole content of the `TextReader` to a File. I cannot use `ReadToEnd()` and write all to a file at once, because the content can be of high size.

Can someone give me a sample/tip how to do this in Blocks?

Comment: Just use ReadLine() in a loop until it returns *null*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using (var textReader = File.OpenText("input.txt"))
using (var writer = File.CreateText("output.txt"))
{
    do
    {
        string line = textReader.ReadLine();
        writer.WriteLine(line);
    } while (!textReader.EndOfStream);
}
```

Comment: I think a do-while loop would be better here

Comment: Your code is invalid. You shouldn't read a line before the `do`, and the order of the read and the write are mixed

Answer (score 1):

Something like this. Loop through the reader until it returns `null` and do your work. Once done, close it.

```
String line;

try 
{
  line = txtrdr.ReadLine();       //call ReadLine on reader to read each line
  while (line != null)            //loop through the reader and do the write
  {
   Console.WriteLine(line);
   line = txtrdr.ReadLine();
  }
}

catch(Exception e)
{
  // Do whatever needed
}


finally 
{
  if(txtrdr != null)
   txtrdr.Close();    //close once done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`TextReader.ReadLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// assuming stream is your TextReader
using (stream)
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@"FileLocation"))
{
   while (!stream.EndOfStream)
   {
        var line = stream.ReadLine();
        sw.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```